# Sum of floor and divisor

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

How can one calculate

$$\sum_{k=1}^n d(k) \lfloor \frac{n}{k} \rfloor$$

where $d(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$?

The original problem is counting triples $(a, b, c)$ such that $a$ divides $b$ and $b$ divides $c$, where $a, b, c$ are natural numbers not greater than $n$.

Comment: You seem to know some $\LaTeX$ syntax.  See this [introduction to posting mathematical notation here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) with `MathJax`.

Comment: The values of this function appear in the _On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences_ as sequence [A061201](http://oeis.org/A061201).  An approximate formula and an efficient method for exact calculation are given.

Comment: What do you mean by "how to calculate"? Note that there is a link to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3122799/constant-function-under-convolution-with-3 since $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n d(k) \lfloor \frac{n}{k} \rfloor = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n (1*1*1)(k)$